# How do I change the lock-screen wallpaper?

Tags: settings, lock-screens, 2.1-eclair, launcherpro

I've lost the ability to change my lock screen wallpaper (in the course of trigger-happy removal of some phone company apps). I used to be able to do `'Menu > Wallpaper'` and be prompted for either the phone or lock screen, but now this stage doesn't appear and I'm taken straight to the `'Select wallpaper from'` screen.

I'm looking for a way to get the lock/home screeen prompt back or failing that, possibly the  location where the active wallpaper is stored in the file system if that would work, or an app that would let me change the lock screen wallpaper directly. (No luck with Google.)

I'm using an Orange San Francisco (ZTE Blade) running Android 2.1.1

*Edit*:   and Launcher Pro.

Comment: With the standard Android launcher, and with the launcher modifications made by most manufacturers, the home screen and lock screen wallpaper are the same. I think your problem is Launcher Pro, if you temporarily switch back to your phone's default launcher this should just work.

Comment: Yep, it was Launcher Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this issue. I'm using LG GT540. When using default LG home screen, I can change the LockScreen Wallpaper.

But if I use any other Launchers the option is not there.

Now what I'm doing is: I will switch to LG Homescreen just for changing the Wallpaper and then will switch back to LauncherPro.

You should do something like this. I know this is not the answer you are looking for; I'm just giving you some hints.

Comment: Thanks Aji. I forgot to mention I'm also running Launcher Pro. I've removed the Orange home screen switcher unfortunately.

Comment: I used 'Home Switcher' app to get back to the Android home screen and could then change the lock wallpaper. Feature request for Launcher Pro  to be able to do this I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your gallery select which picture you want to use. Then press set as and it will bring up the choice to set as wallpaper or set as lock screen. Crop the picture and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

On the ZTE axon mini.. Goto your lock screen then swipe from bottom to top while phone is located, that brings up the gallery for the lock screen... Pick a wallpaper and that it.... For Android lollipop...

Answer (score 0):

I have a zte max and I'm also using Launcher pro and found a way to change my wallpaper for my lock screen.

Go to GALLERY
THEN CHOOSE A PHOTO
SELECT "SET AS"
Then you should have a choice between Wallpaper and lock screen wallpaper...

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the gallery and choose your picture, there should be an option to set it for the lock screen. Or as someone previously said, try changing back to the default launcher. And usually launchers have their backups which do store whatever changes you have made. If yours has a restore backup option you can do that too

Answer (score 0):

If u swipe up from the vary base of your phone on the lock screen and keep trying periodically, I managed to get the wallpaper options come up eventually

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the lockscreen image from gallery then restart your phone, it'll be there ipon reboot